# How do I fix a network error received from axios response react native

Tags: javascript, url, networking, frontend, backend

We recently updated the URL in the backend, and this same URL is being used in the frontend. However, the recently changed URL is not functioning as expected. I have verified the functionality of several other URLs, and they are all working correctly. The issue seems to be isolated to this specific URL since it's working fine in Postman. Unfortunately, when accessed through the frontend, it's giving us a "Network Error" message.

I already applied all stackoverflow solutions which already available

```
  const getUserCart = async () => {
    const URL = `${BASE_URL}orders/getcart/`;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Token ${accessToken}`, // + isLogin,
      },
    };
    let body = {
      user: await AsyncStorage.getItem("username")
    }
    await axios
      .post(URL, body, config)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.cart_detail && res.data.cart_detail[0].items.length == 0) {
          return;
        }
        setNoOfItemsInCart(res.data.cart_detail[0]?.items.length);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setNoOfItemsInCart(0);
        console.log('get user cart error', err);
      });
  };
```

here is error

[image]